# Reason of putting clarified ghee on Modak

Tags: indian-cuisine, ghee

"Modak" is the sweet dish generally prepared for Lord Ganesha in India. "Ukadiche Modak" is the sub-type of Modak. It is usually cooked in steamer. It does not get fried (or deep fried). I would like to know what is the reason of putting clarified ghee on Modak while eating?

[image: Modak]

Image courtesy- Google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golden goodness of ghee has a special value in the culture and cuisine of Indian sub-continent since ancient times. [Ayurveda](https://svasthaayurveda.com/ghee-an-ayurvedic-superfood-and-its-many-health-benefits/) suggests it promotes digestion and increase the absorption of nutrients.

Adding warm ghee to any meal enhances the taste significantly. An example is the 'tadka/tarka' added to lentils('daal') or pouring ghee over boiled rice to enhance the taste. Probably the main reason of putting ghee on steamed Modak is to enhance the taste.

From the story behind the [traditional association of Modak with this festival](https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/ganesh-chaturthi-2018-heres-why-ganpati-bappa-loves-modak-or-laddoo-1915805) my guess is that ghee was added to Modak to make it soft, tasty, easy to eat and filling.